# Suddenly receiving 403 Forbidden errors during curl

Tags: php, curl

This code has been running for 7 years without a problem in partnership with several online retailers.  Suddenly a few days ago, on one company's site (from whom I have permission), I start getting 403 Forbidden errrors.  I'm assuming they accidentally (or not accidentally) blocked my server's IP.  I just wanted to ask you fine people if you think there's something else happening.

```
        $c = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

        // Grab the data.
        $html = curl_exec($c);
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: add ```$stderrh=tmpfile();curl_setopt_array($c,[CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$stderrh]);$html = curl_exec($c);/* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 */rewind($stderrh);$verbose=stream_get_contents($stderrh);fclose($stderrh);echo $verbose;```  and then post the verbose log

Comment: pastebin it, pastebin.com or paste.debian.net or pastebin.centos.org or something like that

Comment: @hanshenrik https://pastebin.com/SnQpUYu7

Comment: it's an IP block. if the site admin can't (literally, or maybe just can't be arsed) to figure out why you're IP-blocked, then just get a proxy (for example, the cheapest vps on ramnode.com is $15/year, which is $1.25/month, just has 128MB ram, but with the OpenVZ shared kernel, that's more than enough to run a proxy)

Comment: @hanshenrik Thanks for your help. I have another question. I'm using a proxy now, and it's working...roughly 50% of the time.  The other 50% i'm getting cURL error number: 7 User was rejected by the SOCKS5 server (1 1).  If I wait a few minutes and try again, it will work, but that's not very efficient. Care to shed some light on that for me? Also, if you add your answer, I'll mark it as the accepted one. Thanks for your time.

Comment: in case it's helpful, I used these resources to use a proxy

https://www.vpnuniversity.com/tutorial/pia-socks-proxy

https://www.bestproxyandvpn.com/help/tutorials/proxy/using-proxies-in-php.html

Comment: add `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => false, CURLOPT_KEEP_SENDING_ON_ERROR => true` and make another VERBOSE log

Answer (score 0):

I would say something changed on the remote server to block you and not on your end.

Code that hasn't failed in years doesn't just stop without something on the outside to influence it.